# What is emperical version of Kendall's tau and can be used as a dependecy measure?

Tags: independence, kendall-tau

I know Kendall's tau as a commonly used measure of dependency. I read that it is inconsistent as an independence test, and hence, another version of consistent Kendall's tau has been introduced and known as Tau star. Also, Kendall's tau is commonly used as a measure of dependence. So, that means, based on my understanding, it is also inconsistent as a measure of dependency. I read two publications about using tau star instead of another independence test and their implementation in the R program. I was then confused about the empirical version and the population version. Both packages/publications refer to empirical versions. So, my point is, can I use the empirical version to measure the dependency among two variables?

The sources of packages and publications are:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/independence/index.html (first package)
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TauStar/index.html (second package)
- https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-20/issue-2/A-consistent-test-of-independence-based-on-a-sign-covariance/10.3150/13-BEJ514.full (open access publication)

Comment: Presumably, the "empirical" version is used when you have a sample from a population, and the "population" version is used when you are analyzing the entire population.

Comment: As a side note, which isn't authoritative, I would be cautious about suggesting this tau-star statistic is similar to Kendall's tau.  It seems to be quite a different statistic, with different properties,  and used for a quite different purpose.  As far as I can tell, it's more similar in purpose to Hoeffding's D for ordinal data.

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico  Thanks for your comment. The author of tau star has mentioned that it can be used as measure of dependency, but introduce it as an independent test.

Comment: It would be worth making clear in your question what $\tau$ is not consistent against -- i.e. general dependence (!). That it doesn't pick up what it was never designed to is hardly surprising. Otherwise it seems a bit like posting that the t-test is inconsistent (because it doesn't pick up differences in kurtosis), without mentioning what you're looking at.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your comment. The question has been updated and becomes more clear, hopefully.